# Converting existing jQuery from click function to auto display with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, homepage text is only displayed via a click function which initiates a slide out.

What I would like to do, is to change this so that it doesn't require a click to display. I'm wanting the text to display (fade in) after about 3 seconds of the page loading.

This is what I have at present:-

```
$('.introbox span').replaceWith(function(){

return '\
    <div class="slideOutTip '+$(this).attr('class')+'" style="'+$(this).attr('style')+'">\
        \
        <div class="tipVisible">\
            <div class="tipIcon"><div class="plusIcon"></div></div>\
            <span class="tipTitle">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</span>\
        </div>\
        \
        <div class="slideOutContent">\
            <p>'+$(this).html()+'</p>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
});
```

It is when the 'plusIcon' is clicked, that the text slides out and is visible.

The listen out for the click function is...

```
$('.tipVisible').bind('click',function(){
    var tip = $(this).parent();
```

So I'm presuming this is where I need to convert the necessary to use autoload with perhaps a setDelay and FadeIn although I'm not 100%.

Please could someone advise how this can be altered to not use a click but auto display after delay? Thanks in advance.

Attempted to add code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/sXWag/2/) if it is easier to see what I'm trying to do - thanks.

Comment: What is the rest of the body of the click handler function?

Comment: Here is the code at jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/sXWag/2/ When the pink box is clicked, the text slides out (but for some reason it isn't in jsfiddle). Hope this is of some use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: make a function with what you do at `.tipVisible.click` and then set a `window.setTimeout(yourFunction, 3000);`

@Comment: Your JS is already pretty complex, I probably would reorganize and recode everything so I can just give you a hint how it could be implemented (didn't work right away when I added it in your fiddle, but I'm a bit too lazy to find the problem there).

```
    var animate = function(obj) {
        var tip = obj ? $(obj).parent() : $(".tipVisible").parent();

        /* If a open/close animation is in progress, exit the function */
        if (tip.is(':animated')) return false;

        if (tip.find('.slideOutContent').css('display') == 'none') {
            tip.trigger('slideOut');
        }
        else tip.trigger('slideIn');
    }

    window.setTimeout( animate, 3000);

    $('.tipVisible').bind('click', function() {
        animate(this);
    });
```

EDIT: Well [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sXWag/6/) is doing something at least, now you have to figure out what needs to be done when and how ;)

PS: You used jQuery but loaded Mootools framework... Mootools doesn't know $(document).ready()

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for your reply. I tried similar, with the following but it didn't seem to do anything. $('.tipVisible').click(function(){ setTimeout("$(this).parent()", 1500); });

Comment: $(this).parent() is not a function, you must provide a function name for setTimeout. Can you post the content of bind('click', function() { ? So I can get an idea how to help you.

Comment: Please see posted jsfiddle (above) - let me know if this doesn't really help you and I'll paste the code in here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Simon - ah yes, I forgot to change the framework from mootools. Your revision still requires a click event to display, whereas I wish to remove this entirely (I think) so that a click is not required to slide out text. Thanks

Comment: Well then you just need to remove the click binding on .tibVisible